# Activating virtualenv leads to terminal losing its color

Tags: python, gnome-terminal, virtualization

I am using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. To make an environment, I need to enter `sudo -s` which leads to `Command not installed...` (as seen below) although the sudo privileges are provided.

The entire process can be seen as

[image: ordeal]

How to get the terminal colors back ?

Comment: also, why do you need to run `sudo -s` while you already have a shell as root user

Comment: What does your `workon wrk`script do exactly?

Comment: I probably got something wrong while setting up `virtualenvwrapper` and could no longer make virtualenvs without entering the `sudo -s`. And
`workon` is a tool of `virtualenvwrapper` that helps me activate the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

The color of your terminal is defined by some environment variables like  `PS1`, but each time you start a new bash shell (like when your run `sudo -s`), the new shell enviroment is initialized by running the .bashrc of the current user (here the user is root whose .bashrc is at */root/.bashrc*, and by default root's .bashrc doesn't define colors).

In the same idea virtualenv activation script replace the `PS1` enviroment variables in order to add the enviroment name in the prompt and thus may remove the colors at the same time.

Here you seem to restore colors by running your own user .bashrc manually, but if you want a more permanent solution, you need to edit root .bashrc as well as your virtual env activation script to set the PS1 value you want.

This is for the color problem. As for your other errors, the virtualenv binary doesn't seam to be installed correctly, so maybe try reinstalling it.